# Website for drawing math graphs

Tags: graphing-functions

Is there any website where I can label and draw a mathematical graph using equations instead of a table of coordinates?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/, https://www.wolframalpha.com/, thousands of others.

Comment: You can do that with LaTeX.

Comment: Not a website, but a program that I can recommend: https://www.padowan.dk/

Comment: https://www.geogebra.org

Comment: Just googling "graphing" produced three websites as first results in the following order: Desmos, GeoGebra, Symbolab.

Answer (score 1):

[GeoGebra.org](https://www.geogebra.org/) and especially [GeoGebra.org/graphing](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing) is a useful website to do this. Furthermore, you can export the files and save them as `.ggb`, `.png`, `.svg`, `.pdf`, `.tikz`, etc..

Here is an example for $f(x)=4x+9$:
[image: GeoGebra.org]